# Optimistic locking on merge operation using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have production code running for past 2 years. Now we have noticed that there is concurrency issue in Update operation. I am Using JPA as my ORM. In update request i am using

```
this.entityManager.merge(entity);
```

Now we want to use optimistic lock to avoid this concurrency. I have done some searching in google. I think following will take care

```
this.entityManager.lock(entity, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
```

here my doubt is does we really need a @Version in the table. I guess my client won't agree in adding this column now.

Can someone tell me is there any better way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in JPA, no.  JPA uses the version column to maintain it's consistency and there doesn't appear to be any way around that.

In Hibernate there are semantics to get around this:

```
Optimistic-lock = ‘all’
```

When you set the optimistic-lock attribute on the  element in the Hibernate mapping file to the value ‘all’, you are telling Hibernate to check that no column in the associated row has changed since the persistent object was retrieved and before updating the row in the database.

Read more: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/hibernate-optimistic-lock-without-"

Comment: I have dropped lock plan, instead i am asking user to pass the Lastupdated date and checking against DB. if both are matching i will allow update else error message. Thank u for ur time.